# Query by minute in time column in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In Microsoft SQL Server, I have a time column called `TimeCol` (example data is "2022-01-13 12:43:03.820"). I am merging two tables according to the time column (my join code is shown below).

Is there a chance to do the join operation independent of seconds, for example, I want "2022-01-13 12:43:03.820" to merge with "2022-01-13 12:43:07.310"

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.[TimeCol] = t2.[TimeCol]
```

Comment: you can try to cast these columns to SMALLDATETIME

Comment: With the database already designed, I have no chance to change the type of the time column. Is there any chance I can do this inside the query

Comment: Of course. SELECT T1.* FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON CAST(T1.TIMECOL AS SMALLDATETIME)=CAST(T2.TIMECOL AS SMALLDATETIME)

Comment: Or you may also consider using a computed column in the table